# Store message in a table even if user is offline signalR

Tags: c#, signalr

I was just wondering if it was possible to store data in a db from a hub method even if there is no connected users?

So i have a basic method that sends a message to each user in a group from outside a group and this works great (sends message and stores in db) but i have only just noticed that if there is no connected users the method to store data into the db does not fire. One would assume when the client side function fires it still gets sent to the hub for processing?

A little code snippet for a visual reference.

```
public void Send(string campaignName, string message, string name, string email, string query)
{
    //Save Support Request
    int campaignID = Business.Campaign.getCampaignIDByCampaignName(campaignName);

    string n = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(name);
    string e = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(email);
    string q = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(query);

    Business.SupportRequest.newSupportRequest(n, e, q, campaignID);

    //If users online send message
    List<Business.User> users = Business.User.getUsersFromCampaign(campaignName);
    foreach (var u in users) 
    {
        Clients.Client(u.connectionID).sendSupportRequest(message);
    }
}
```

I could easily call another function from the client side to insert to the db but id rather keep it within the Hub.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: if you are wanting to send this to the users in the foreach you could just check `if(u.IsNullOrEmpty || u.Length > 0)` then call the sendSupportRequest(Message) however why would you want to send a message to someone that's not connected unless you plan on having those messages get to that user the next time that they log in..

Comment: @DJKRAZE sending a message to user works fine when their connected, which makes sense and the same time it stores to a db. What i want to do is save to the db even if the users are disconnected. My save method does not fire if no user is connected.

Comment: then what part of what I suggested do you not understand..? can you not write a conditional check to check for either and still save ...?

Comment: @DJKRAZE apologies, i don't think I'm understanding your comment. sendSupportRequest essentially would fire only if the users are connected so checking is irrelevant but newSupportRequest(saves to db method) should store to db connected or not but at the moment its only firing when users are connected to the hub. newSupportRequest basically is for reviewing later.

Comment: I don't think that you understand the basic logical check that you would need here.. inside your foreach loop you need to add a check for `IsNullOrEmpty` so if they are online I am going to assume `u` would have a valid user if not the you can still call the save to db method does that make sense..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I don't know if my original question was lacking in a more thorough description but again i don't need to check IsNullOrEmpty. I dont mean to be rude but it has nothing to do with the users! Business.SupportRequest.newSupportRequest(n, e, q, campaignID) was not firing at all, it is not coupled what so ever to the users. I found the problem anyhow and i understand logical patterns very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question. Yes you can fire another method inside the hub even if there are no users connected.

My problem was HTMLEncode was not firing when calling from an iframe on a separate domain. It was throwing a Null exception. Debugging with signalR is slightly more complicated than the norm.

Regards,